# How to manage a huge transaction that keeps growing with more functionality?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database-design, transactions

We have an application where all transactions round trips must complete in 30s.
The issue that I have is more and more functionality is added and soon that threshold of 30 secs will be surpassed.

An example:
Adding a product in the formulary is a huge transaction that is committed only after all the following pieces are complete successfully:

1. Product identification (name, NDC, etc...) 1 table
2. Product Groups (free drug, etc... ) (another table)
3. Product labels  (another table)
4. Product Clinical Comments (another table)
5. Product Configurations (another table)
6. Product can contain other products when it is set up as a bin

And more functionality to come in such as

8. Product program participation ( 340B, buy-in etc...)

etc....

The transaction also takes time because it has to propagate the exact same values with different system generated keys to every active practice.

So If Tylenol is added to the formulary with key = 1 and there are 600 active practices, the transaction will insert 601 rows with the exact same values but different keys per practice such that each practice has its own copy to configure to their preferences.

Redesign is not an option due to lack of time and resources.  As more and more functionality is added to this transaction, I wonder if there is a proper way to "divide and conquer" so as to the transaction can make it in 30 secs?

By "divide and conquer" I mean functional groupings.  So in my scenario, the add product can be broken into Group 1 -- minimum essentials (identification, groups, configurations), Group 2 -- Labels and Clinical comments, Group 3 -- Program Participation.

However the "divide and conquer" would mean a multi-stop workflow for the application and the user.  The user after adding Group1 will have to go do Group2 and Group 3.

Currently the transaction on the average takes 10 secs.  It is worse approximately 17 secs when 1 product belong to multiple groups.

The main table already has 7 indexes.  The add sproc has more 1800 lines.

Has anyone faced this issue?  Any comments will be greatly appreciated.

Thank you!

Comment: When you say a transaction has to complete within 30 sec, are you talking about a SQL transaction as in begin transaction / end transaction, or are you saying that all processing for a given process needs to complete within 30 sec?

Comment: 30 secs include C# application client call time and client receive time.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on the details of the work performed and the version of SQL Server in use, it might be possible to gain some efficiency through [parallel insertion](http://blogs.technet.com/technet_blog_images/b/sql_server_sizing_ha_and_performance_hints/archive/2013/10/10/parallel-insert-in-sql-server-2014.aspx) and/or [parallel query](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178065%28v=sql.105%29.aspx).

If you cannot redesign the database, *and* these transactions are already running substantially as efficiently as possible for their requirements and the database design, *and* they still aren't fast enough, then your options are few: faster hardware or splitting up the transaction into multiple separate ones.  The latter might constitute adhering to the letter of the law but violating its spirit, or might not even satisfy the letter of the law at all.

It is possible that you cannot improve your performance other than by redesigning the database and software, but I don't have enough information to evaluate that.

Comment: Parallel insertion is a great ideal  I may have to go that route.  We are currently on sql server 2012 but if the application gets to a point where it reaches the time inverval of 30 secs and the business does not give the team time to redesign the database and the application, I at least one suggestion to make things possible -- parallel insertion.  In my scenario, Group 2 and Group 3 and Groupx-y could all go in as parallel insertions.